# Boostrap chat keeping message box at bottom of screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

Hi I am trying to have a row stay at the bottom of the screen for a message send input box, the problem I am having is that if I set the row:

```
row d-flex position-absolute bottom-0
```

the columns are not taking the horizontal space in the row.

here is my Boostrap 5 code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" />
  <title>Stripe connect</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 bg-primary sidebar">
        <div class="px-3 py-3"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="col bg-secondary">
        <div class="row bg-success d-flex align-items-start flex-column vh-100">
          ff
        </div>

        <div class="row d-flex position-absolute bottom-0">
          <div class="col bg-danger">ff</div>
          <div class="col">ff</div>
          <div class="col">ff</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and here is an image:

[columns are to the left and not taking up the full width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22kM7.png)

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Since you're deliberately placing the utility classes also specify the `start-0` and `end-0` declarations as well. Cheers

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 bg-primary sidebar">
      <div class="px-3 py-3"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col bg-secondary">
      <div class="row bg-success d-flex align-items-start flex-column vh-100">
        ff
      </div>

      <div class="row d-flex position-absolute bottom-0 start-0 end-0">
        <div class="col bg-danger">ff</div>
        <div class="col">ff</div>
        <div class="col">ff</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the help, the problem with setting the start-0 is is that the bottom row takes all space at the bottom and overlaps the blue section as well, we just want it to take up the space of the green section. we are building a messaging app, where we are trying to add the send message input box. Thanks